# Debian 11 Server - vsftpd virtual users don't work, permission issue?

Tags: linux, debian, permissions, vsftpd

I have a Debian 11 VM with vsftpd enabled for my local user. I want to create a virtual, FTP only user (who should be rw limited to their home directory). I followed this https://help.ubuntu.com/community/vsftpd Unfortunately this not only doesn't work, it also breaks my local user. The user is named `editor` but rest (paths etc) is the same as in the guide.

Connecting a local user (copied from Filezilla, 100% sure password is correct)

```
Status: Connecting to 10.0.1.8:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Status: Insecure server, it does not support FTP over TLS.
Command: USER tomsikr
Response: 331 Please specify the password.
Command: PASS **********
Response: 530 Login incorrect.
Error: Critical error: Could not connect to server
```

Connecting a virtual user

```
Status: Connecting to 10.0.1.8:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Status: Insecure server, it does not support FTP over TLS.
Command: USER editor
Response: 331 Please specify the password.
Command: PASS ******
Response: 500 OOPS: cannot change directory:/home/vftp/editor
Error: Critical error: Could not connect to server
```

`/etc/vsftpd.conf` (pastebin com/9k9r3rLe)

```
listen=NO
listen_ipv6=YES
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
virtual_use_local_privs=YES
write_enable=YES
dirmessage_enable=YES
use_localtime=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES

xferlog_enable=YES
xferlog_file=/var/log/vsftpd.log
xferlog_std_format=YES

log_ftp_protocol=YES
chroot_local_user=YES
chroot_list_enable=YES
chroot_list_file=/etc/vsftpd.chroot_list
secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd/empty
pam_service_name=vsftpd
rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
rsa_private_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
ssl_enable=NO

userlist_deny=YES
userlist_file=/etc/vsftpd.denied_users

pasv_enable=Yes
pasv_min_port=10100
pasv_max_port=10110

pam_service_name=vsftpd.virtual

guest_enable=YES

user_sub_token=$USER

local_root=/home/vftp/$USER

chroot_local_user=YES

hide_ids=YES
```

`/etc/vsftpd.chroot_list` (only contains my local user, aka me)

```
tomsikr
```

`/etc/vsftpd.denied_users`

```
root
```

The virtual user `editor` is in `/etc/vsftpd/vsftpd-virtual-user.db`

`/etc/pam.d/vsftpd.virtual`

```
#%PAM-1.0 auth required pam_userdb.so db=/etc/vsftpd/vsftpd-virtual-user
account required pam_userdb.so db=/etc/vsftpd/vsftpd-virtual-user
session required pam_loginuid.so
```

Any help would be appreciated because I hit a wall. I'm not a Linux admin, I'm learning this on the fly

Comment: Please format the text in your question so it represents reality

Comment: Excuse me what? @roaima

Comment: I've done it for you. You might like to take a look with the [Edit] button to see how I marked up the formatting for the code

Comment: The error message `Response: 500 OOPS: cannot change directory:/home/vftp/editor` seems to be the driver here. Does that directory exist? What is its permissions (`ls -ld /home/vftp/editor`)? Is `vftp` an error that should really be `vsftp` (I don't know - just asking)?

Comment: Hmm, you are right, I might have put a wrong folder in the config. I won't be in the office until Tuesday, so I can't confirm or deny it right now (not allowed to have any remote desktop)

But that doesn't explain why it broke my regular user's connection.

Comment: Okay, so it was because the folder didn't exist. Now just need to figure out how permissions work (I can only read the folder, not write) and my main user is still broken